# Ajax Caching and Correct Format used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a JavaScript event that is called like so:

```
function addEvent(date, resId) {

$("#appPlaceholder").load("/Schedule/Add?date=" + date.format()+"&resourceId="+resId,
             function () {
                 $('#eventModal').modal('show');
             });

    };
```

However am I using the correct standards to format/pass my variables?

`.load("/Schedule/Add?date=" + date.format()+"&resourceId="+resId)` ??

Also I need to make sure the load does not cache, how can I prevent this.
Any Examples much appreciated.

Comment: is it working or not? Nothing wrong with url query string structure assuming `date.format()` returns a string. Adding a timestamp variable in url query and `Date.now()` as value will prevent caching by assuring a unique url is used

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about URL encoding, use `encodeURIComponent`:

```
var date = encodeURIComponent(date.format());
var id = encodeURIComponent(resId);
```

To prevent from caching, add to the end some random value. For example:

```
'&v=' + Math.random()
```